# Call fragment from another fragment after some delay

Tags: android, fragment

I searched all over the web, couldn't find a good reference on how to call fragment from another fragment.

`Fragment A -> Fragment B` (fragment A calls fragment B after 3 seconds)

Comment: What do you mean "call"? From Fragment A call method in Fragment B?

Comment: no, call fragment B from A

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all you need to consider that it's a very bad idea to keep somehow a direct reference from FragmentA to FragmentB. Why:

1. FragmentB may be recreated and you may keep a reference to an older reference of FragmentB. So you have a memory leak.
2. FragmentB may be not created, added or visible. So you would have a null/unusable reference.

For this reason you need to consider methods that base on sending messages from `FragmentA` to `FragmentB`. I see several options:

- **Send a broadcast message** using a custom action from `FragmentA`. `FragmentB` registers itself as a receiver for this kind of message (in onCreate/onResume/onAttach and de-register in onDestroy/onPause/onDetach) and when the message arrives it can handle it. This is very suitable if you have no data to send from `FragmentA` to `FragmentB` or if you do these are primitive types or easy-to-implement `Parcelables`. Here's an example:

Have this in `FragmentA`:

```
private void sendMessageToFragmentB(String someData) {
    Intent messageIntent = new Intent("com.your_package.A_TO_B_ACTION");
    messageIntent.putExtra("DATA_VALUE", someData);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).sendBroadcast(messageIntent);
}
```

While in `FragmentB` you could have this:

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
    private BroadcastReceiver messagesFromAReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if ("com.your_package.A_TO_B_ACTION".equals(intent.getAction())) {
                String dataFromA = intent.getStringExtra("DATA_VALUE");
                dataFromAReceived(dataFromA);
            }
        }
    };

    protected void dataFromAReceived(String data) {
        // here you have the data
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        IntentFilter messageFromAIntentFilter = new IntentFilter("com.your_package.A_TO_B_ACTION");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(messagesFromAReceiver,
                messageFromAIntentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(messagesFromAReceiver);
    }

}
```

- **Use the hosting activity as a proxy**: The host activity implements some kind of interface defined in `FragmentA` and when requested it can search if it can find `FragmentB` and if so call some method in there. The advantage is that you can send any data, no matter its weight. The base idea is descrived in [Android dev articles](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html). To exemplify, you could have `FragmentA` as:

  public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

  ```
  public static interface CallerProxy {
      public void sendCustomMessage(Object... dataParams);
  }

  private CallerProxy proxyActivity;

  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
      super.onAttach(activity);
      if (activity instanceof CallerProxy) {
          this.proxyActivity = (CallerProxy) activity;
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void onDetach() {
      super.onDetach();
      this.proxyActivity = null;
  }

  private void sendMessageToFragmentB(String someData) {
      if (proxyActivity != null) {
          // send whatever data
          proxyActivity.sendCustomMessage(new Integer(1), new Object());
          // or don't send anything ...
          proxyActivity.sendCustomMessage();
      }
  }
  ```

  }

The proxy activity would have at least these methods and signature:

```
public class MyProxyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements CallerProxy {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // call setContentView and then make sure you've added FragmentA and
        // FragmentB.

    }

    @Override
    public void sendCustomMessage(Object... dataParams) {
        // FragmentB must be identified somehow, either by tag,
        // either by id. Suppose you'll identify by tag. This means you've added
        // it previously with this tag
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FragmentB-TAG");
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentB fragB = (FragmentB) fragment;
            fragB.dataFromAReceived(dataParams);
        }
    }
}
```

While in `FragmentB` all you need is a method that can be called with above sent parameters:

```
public void dataFromAReceived(Object ... data) {
    // here you have the data
}
```

- **Use or implement some sort of event bus**. Some [general details here](http://eventbus.org/). For Android I remember that [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) event bus was very handy and easy to use. Here's [a link](http://corner.squareup.com/2012/07/otto.html) with this. This is very similar to first option as you need anyway to register and un-register.

In the end it depends on what you need to send as a message, when should it be received and how flexible does it need to be. ... your choice!

Enjoy programming!

Answer (score 1):

Fragments are not supposed to connect to each other directly, that may be your problem in finding a decent guide to do this.

Your approach makes the assumption that a fragment B will always be reachable (and ready) for a fragment A to interact, and that is actually not true, will kill the flexibility of your Fragment and will cause you problems in the future.

A better approach to interaction of Fragments is to talk only through interfaces that talk directly to a activity that can handle who is alive when where and should receive what.

-> http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

This Android guide above, specifically on the last topic, shows you how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

**i hope this code help you..**

**in your first fragment add this code**

onCreateView

```
LocalBroadcastManager broadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity());

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("update");
    // Here you can add additional actions which then would be received by the BroadcastReceiver

    broadcastManager.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);



@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    super.onDestroyView();
}

private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action != null && action.equals("update")) {
            // perform your update
            getOngoingOrderData();
        }

    }
};
```

**in your second fragment add this code where you send broadcast..**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("update");

                        LocalBroadcastManager broadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity());
                        broadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
```