# How to pass a Fragment to another Fragment?

Tags: android, fragment

My app has one main `Activity` with a `FrameLayout` to load some `Fragments`, most of them managing http data requests.

When the connection is lost, I start a specific `Fragment` "NoConnectionFragment" with a text "No internet connection" and a `Button` "Retry".

When clicking on "Retry" I want to reload the previous `Fragment`, that failed to load the data, with some data to specify the state of the `Fragment`.

I can pass the state data in a `Bundle`, but how can I pass to the NoConnectionFragment data on what `Fragment` to reload? Is there any way to pass the `Fragment` directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just storing the name of the previous fragment.

ex: If FragmentA is active before NoConnectionFragment is launched, keep a static variable int the parent activity that stores this state.

```
static int PREV_FRAGMENT_INDEX; //index can be 0 for FragmentA, 1 for FragmentB etc
```

When retry button is clicked, just check this variable to launch the appropriate fragment:

```
onClick(View v)
{
    switch(getActivity().PREV_FRAGMENT_INDEX)
    {
      case 0: //launch Fragment A

      case 1: //launch Fragment B etc
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no way to pass directly the Fragment class name or something to avoid the switch/case?

Comment: I don't believe so. If you it was an activity you could store it in Class<?> variable and pass it in when you create an Intent but fragment manager requires fully initialized fragment objects so just the name wouldn't do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a fragment to another Fragment because fragments are not supposed to work that way and also fragment are managed by FragmentManagers. What you could do is to [pass data from a Fragment to another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19321466/1051783).

Comment: So how can I know what `Fragment` I should load when clicking Retry?

Comment: You could pass that responsibility to the owner activity. And from activity decide what fragment to load or if the fragment already exists, send a message to it.

Comment: But how can I know which Fragment to load? Can I pass the class name or something?

Comment: I suppose you're starting the data-loading fragment (let's call it `DataFragment`) from activity. If you get a network failure in `DataFragment` then the activity is showing the `NoConnectionFragment`, right? If so, when the button gets clicked, have the activity to re-launch `DataFragment` or if `DataFragment` is already present, call a method of it. Does it make sense?